# Graph Representation of N Genomes

Tags: graph, graph-algorithm, genome

I have n sequences each of 3 billion length (Human Genome). I am looking for efficient way to store/represent these n strings. One natural way that I can think of is graphs, where nodes can store common sub-strings among these sequences and directed edges are present between nodes where we see variation, and a set of paths P =  P1 . . .  Pq where each path represent original sequence..

For Example:

Suppose we have four strings S1 = ATCGGCT, S2 = ATCGATT, S3 = GTCGGCT, S4 = GTCGATT.  Then the Graph should be as follows

[image]

The problem I am facing is how to find maximum common subsequence that is common among n sequence and if not then n-1 sequence and so on. Can anybody point me towards the resource where I can get the direction or pseudocode to do so ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Given that each of those pointers will probably be a 32-bit integer, and you'll need to keep track of which path each string takes somehow, I don't see how this approach will ever reach the efficiency of storing each string separately, encoding each base as 2 bits.